# How to detect when the user has scrolled to a certain area on the page using JavaScript? and then run an animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations

How to detect when the user has scrolled to a certain area on the page using JavaScript? and then run an animation?
I need to run animation when scrolled to that section please help if you know any part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API):

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((nodes)=>{
    nodes.forEach(node =>
      node.target.classList.toggle('visible', node.isIntersecting)
    )
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.node'))
```

```css
.node {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin: 500px;
  transition: 1s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.node.visible {
  background: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='node'>x</div>
```

Comment: Is using this API best method to run animation when scrolled?

Comment: yes it absolutely is the best way to do this

Answer (score 0):

u probably want to take a look on the Intersection Observer API which provides just that ability.

from Intersection Observer MDN documentation -

> The Intersection Observer API provides a way to asynchronously observe
> changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor
> element or with a top-level document's viewport.

for more information checkout mdn's page regarding intersection observer API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Is using this API the best method to run animation when scrolled?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be in Vanilla Javascript You could look at this library https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).